# Ways to automate Outlook Application

Tags: outlook, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, office-automation, com-automation

After every patching we test basic Outlook functionality like able to send email etc, wanted to check if there is any way to automate the Outlook UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) or any wrapper around that API with Selenium for getting the job done.